# How to configure silent login to Redmine upon entering to domain?

Tags: ruby, apache, active-directory, ldap, redmine

In my environment all users which registered in the domain are authenticated in the Redmine through LDAP, as described here - [LDAP Authentication](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineLDAP)

Some customers wants automatically login to Redmine, without typing credentials somewhere and immediately go to the `home_url`.

Is it possible?

I tried to use the hack as described here - [Running redmine on Apache2 on Windows; using SSPI authentication; is it possible?](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/127) - but I still should enter the AD credentials when passing the basic authentication (in a separate window).

How to configure silent login to Redmine upon entering to domain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just wrote a post of how to setup it on latest CentOS 7, using single_auth plugin:
http://techutils.bcmedeiros.dev/2016/02/redmine-ad-sso-setup.html

The idea there is to follow the default setup of the single_auth plugin, but using the mod_auth_ntlm_winbind apache module to be the bridge between apache and the ntlm_auth command. ntlm_auth needs samba (in this case samba 4) to be joined in the domain.

Hope it helps!